# how to install ubuntu on a new laptop without ethernet port?

Tags: drivers, wireless, software-installation, gpu-driver

While installing and downloading drivers at  first time installation is it necessary to have ethernet port because I don't have ethernet port and can rely on wireless so can I install ubuntu using wi-fi.?

Comment: You can install Ubuntu without an internet connection. Of course, not updated packages will be installed nor additional software not available in the installation media. And of course you can use Wi-Fi if it is supported automatically.

Comment: Yes you can install without ethernet or wifi (*no network is a QA-tested install*).  If you don't have ethernet, you can connect to wifi before you do the install, and wifi will be used instead of ethernet by the installer (it'll use whatever network is detected and available).  You've provided no specifics as to release, or what issue really concerns you - but installation does **not** require ethernet, nor wifi.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

During the installation you should be asked to connect to your Wi-Fi network. If that does not work at first, you still can install Ubuntu, even without an Internet connection.

**Note:** Make sure you activate the *"Install third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware"* option during the installation process; Wi-Fi and GPU should work OK after installation.

Comment: Yes I can install it but I am having concern regarding wi-fi drivers as i don't have any ethernet port to download at the time of installation.

Comment: You may want to use the "Try Ubuntu without installing" option to check if your WiFi works or not before installing.